# All steps of finding a witness Rabin-Miller

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Find a  Rabin-Miller witness of compositeness of $n=49$

I have asked the same question before months but can we have a complete answer of how to find this witness? i mean with complete answer(all steps).sorry for asking again.

Comment: Please edit in a link to the other time you asked. Also, it would help if you include the definition of "Rabin-Miller witness". (Do you know the definition?)

Answer (score 2):

This is again a somewhat stupid case for Miller-Rabin similar to your [Rabin-Miller compositeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1369888/rabin-miller-compositeness),
because you should assume that $n$ is not a square.  You have accepted that answer which containing all the steps, so I do not understand where you have problems. Apart from the fact that Miller-Rabin is non-sense for squares, the simple finding procedure is: Test all $a=2,3,\dots$ with $\gcd(a,n)=1$ if it is a witness for the compositeness.

That said, here is the calculation: Let $n=49$ and $a=2$ the smallest possible candidate, then $n-1=d\times 2^s = 3\times 2^4.$ Now compute 
$$x_0 \equiv a^d \equiv 2^3 \equiv 8 \pmod{49}$$ 
$$x_1 \equiv x_0^2 \equiv 15 \pmod{49}$$ 
$$x_2 \equiv x_1^2 \equiv 29\pmod{49}$$ 
$$x_3 \equiv x_2^2 \equiv 8\pmod{49}$$ 
Thus $a^d\not \equiv 1 \pmod {49}$ and $x_r \equiv a^{2^r d}\not \equiv -1 \pmod {49}$ for $0\le r \le s-1.\,$ Therefore $a=2$ is a witness for the compositeness of $49$.